# Removing queue before nack freezes my app

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I'm kind of new to rabbitmq and i was wondering what is the best way to handle an error I'm having when a delete a queue before I can ack a delivery on that queue.

```
if err := handle(); err != nil {
  delivery.Nack(false, true)
} else {
  delivery.Ack(false)
}
```

The problem with this code is that our queues are created/deleted based on a coordinator external to our dispatcher, so when delivery is Nack and the queue was deleted the system hangs because it keeps trying to requeue the delivery.

To solve the problem I can just check if the:

```
delivery.Nack(false, true)
```

returns an error and I can handle it there. But what would be the best approach to drop this delivery if the Nack method returned an error?

Note: I'm using https://github.com/streadway/amqp

Answer (score 2):

> The problem with this code is that our queues are created/deleted based on a coordinator external to our dispatcher,

that is the problem, right there. i would question why you want to do this, instead of allowing the consumer to define the queue and binding that it needs?

barring the ability to question / change that, an error handler around the `deliver.Nack` is probably your best option. but i think that's an unpleasant workaround for a problem caused by larger design issue